# Eslint setting curly brace directly after [ and after },

Tags: eslint

What's the eslint setting for forcing a curly brace directly after [ and a curly brace directly after }, ?

Instead of:

```
let array = [
    {
        a: "b"
    },
    {
        a: "c"
    }];
```

I want to see following:

```
let array = [{ //curly brace after [
    a: "b"
}, { //curly brace after },
    a: "c"
}];
```

Comment: hey can you let us know what rules you're currently using?

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-bracket-spacing#objectsinarrays might be it, or it could be indenting of `curly-newline` -can't tell without more info

Comment: @DenisTsoi I'm using the eslint:recommended and some rules not related to this question.

Comment: checked on vscode, `eslint:recommended` isn't autoformatting the first example, may have to ask you list out the other rules for me

Comment: @DenisTsoi I cleaned up as much as possible and only have this one left: "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs"]

Comment: try `brace-style: "error"` if you're using `1tbs` - might be conflicting there (default is `1tbs`)

Comment: @DenisTsoi Unfortunately did not help.

Comment: what version of eslint and your code editor?

Comment: @DenisTsoi eslint version 3.18.0. IDE doesn't matter.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek ping. you didn't get further on this, did you?